# Enable AI-based Recommendations for the WSO2 Developer Portal

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I follow the official documentation to add AI-based Recommendations for the Developer Portal by adding this config to deployment.toml folder and restart the server ,but it didn't work.

```
[apim.devportal.recommendations]
recommendations_api = "a5753b42-9dac-44c1-8f01-45688c1bf129"
consumer_key = "c7xp1kfRcp5VCdrNyvy3obZcA6ga"
consumer_secret = "8PQjEZq2uHezRIm7SwVnUfBAvNwa"
max_recommendations = 10
wait_duration = 10
apply_for_all_tenants = false
```

The official documentation link : https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/discover-apis/api-recommendations/#changing-the-default-behavior-of-recommendations

Comment: Did you deploy the recommendations python server locally?

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations are provided through an external server. Previously we had hosted this server in WSO2 cloud and customers can use this server for free after requesting access through the support portal. But this deployment has been put down after sometime. However you can still deploy the server in your own instance and use it for recommendation functionality.

The server can be found in here: https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/master/modules/recommendation-engine.
Follow the instructions and deploy the server.

You can then point to this recommendations server using the following configs.

```
[apim.devportal.recommendations]
recommendations_api = "http:localhost:8082/getRecommendations"
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
max_recommendations = 10
wait_duration = 10
apply_for_all_tenants = true
```

However, there was a regression that broke the feature in APIM 4.1.0 GA and later fixed via an update.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to enable this feature for a specific tenant (since `apply_for_all_tenants = false` in the toml config). In that case have you followed instructions in [1] and enabled recommendations for that particular tenant under Admin portals Advanced Configurations ?

Otherwise if you wish to enable this feature for all tenants you have to set `apply_for_all_tenants = true`

Suggestion: Better to mask sensitive details in the config.

[1]. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/discover-apis/api-recommendations/#enabling-recommendations-only-for-a-specific-tenant

Comment: I have change apply_for_all_tenants = true and nothing happens ,still same problem

Comment: what is the APIM version you are using ? is it 4.1.0 GA release ?

Comment: Yes,i used WSO2 APIM 4.1.0

Comment: I have not tried out this feature, I just checked the code and noticed that the recommendations_api config should be configured as the actual recommendations API service URL [1]. Your config has a UUID value not a URL. [1]. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/recommendationmgt/RecommenderDetailsExtractor.java#LL396C43-L396C43

Comment: Looks like there were some issues with this feature in 4.1.0 GA release and they have been fixed with an update(https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/90) later. In case you have a WSO2 subscription you can try this after upgrading to latest update level. If you do not have a subscription you may add the fix pointed in above git issue as a patch to your deployment.